# How to think as a programmer?

Tags: programming-languages

Had a hard time finding a tag that seemed to fit my question but I hope this does the job.

Anyway, I want to learn programming, and I'm currently taking a python programming course over 10 weeks. I'm in my 5th week right now and I feel I haven't learned much more than the syntax.

I've tried learning programming for I don't know 10 years now, and I always pick up the syntax in a week or two, but after that is when I get stuck and give up. Well, this time I don't want to give up so I'll ask here.

How do I learn to think as a programmer? It doesn't matter how many tutorials I read, all they teach is the syntax, and the syntax is the easy part. If there's one thing I've learned it's that you can't program with syntax alone.

Programming language doesn't really matter because as I've said, I pick up the syntax really quick, and I pretty much have played with most programming languages.

So, is there any tutorials or articles, or even books that go through the thought process of making a program?

I think what would teach me the most would be something where you're taken through the process of making a program in great detail. Not like those books where you make a thousand small programs, but an in-depth view of the making of one program.
///Edit
Thanks guys, you've been a real help, I think I can continue from here!

Comment: This is definitely a "learn by doing" activity. Some people are just naturally good at it, but I know others where it didn't "click" for them until third year Uni. What exactly is it that you have the most trouble in when thinking like a programmer? Also thinking like a programmer is kind of a broad field, I for one have a lot of trouble thinking like a front-end/web programmer, but I am very good at breaking down problems and solving algorithmic challenges etc.

Comment: Well, what I have problems with is knowing how to structure a program and how to build the functions necessary. I guess you could say that I know how the house should look, but I don't know which materials I should use.

Comment: Well the good news is that comes directly from experience. Just keep building stuff, preferably with other people. I go by the 6 month rule, when you look at code you wrote 6 months ago you should be horrified because you have learnt better since then. If you look back and are happy, that means you aren't learning.

Comment: Maybe you could point me to a site with some excercises? I don't mean stuff like codeacademy, but more like a list of excercises you could do. I often notice I have trouble finding stuff to do aswell.

Comment: There's just too many for me to link any here. I would recommend spending a little time deciding on something you want to build, and just build it. Check out github at all the random little projects people build, they are quite funny sometimes. Some of the best projects are inspired by something that just annoys the hell out of them, so they try to write some code to make their life easier.

Answer (score 5):

Congratulations to learning the syntax! As you know the syntax, you can read real programs that other people have written. You can try out modifying them. As you gain experience reading and modifying programs, you will be able to write your own.

As Eric S. Raymond wrote:

> You can learn language features — bits of knowledge — from books, but the mind-set that makes that knowledge into living skill can be learned only by practice and apprenticeship. What will do it is (a) reading code and (b) writing code.

http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/hacker-howto.html#skills1

Comment: And, in line with that idea, you may want to find an open-source program you like and take a look at their github/codeplex/svn/whatever, so you can see the history that project went through -- what changed, in what order, and why.

Answer (score 2):

It's interesting that you've identified something that every programming course I've ever seen simply takes as a given. Think like a programmer. Essentially you either do or you don't, If you don't you can still program, but it won't be natural. The thing is a lot of people can and do, but don't realise that they are.

Forget syntax for a bit.

Lets say you are cleaning out a kitchen cupboard with three shelves, and you want to do without ending up having to clean all the items in the cupboard.
So you empty the cupboard, starting at the bottom (doing it from the top would mess up the stuff below) and you clean from the top shelf down (other wise you'd be sweeping rubbish on to the newly cleaned shelves below) .
If you can think like that, you can be a programmer.

Some people get to the solution quicker than others, but the real trick to being a programmer is syntax and semantics are just noise required to express the solution in a particular programming language.

First get a solution, then implement it in your language of choice. There may end up being better ways of expressing it in that language, but try to first express it in a "language" that feels natural to you, then translate. 
Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Quite an interesting question, especially for me as a teacher.

Programming per-se isn't that difficult. It's just very different from how humans are doing things - and that's what you have to get used to. Always keep in mind: the computer is stupid. It cannot guess what you're trying to tell it. You always have to tell every step. It's NOT (although that is a common comparison) like writing a cookbook - in cookbooks you can assume whoever is reading it can fill little gaps you may have left. The computer cannot.
For me, it's two things that are important.

First, and most likely the more important one: practice. It's ALL about practice. I've never read any books about programming, especially no tutorials. It's all try and error for me. Looked at code, tried to understand it, tried to replicate and modify. Learning by doing. Sure, that may not be everybody's preferred way of learning things - but looking at code from others and understanding it (not TRYing to understand - read, replicate and deubg it until you DO) is the ebst way of learning new techniques.

Second thing is: don't think intuitively - stick with only thinking logically. I have experienced that many people read code, don't fully understand it and then go with "well, I know what it's supposed to do, so those lines there somehow seem to do that". That doesn't do any good for learning programming. The code only does exactly what is written down there. Step by step. If you don't see how that's gonna work out, than most likely the code isn't doing what you think it is.
Same goes for writing code. The first thing you have in your midn when developing a programm is what it is supposed to do. But that is in an non-procedural form - your midn doesn't work procedurally. It works intuitively. In human mindes it's all about ideas and prototypes. There are no exact algorithms, our minds are not powerfull enough to do everything so accurately. SO the next step is to structure your ideas. Split it into small parts. Than split those again. And again. Until you have lots of simple tasks that can be done in a few (normally 10-20 steps at max!) steps. To not loose the big picture, make diagrams, or at least some notes, of how all those small steps should work together at the end. Keep in mind: your brain won't be able to get the whole big thing together in procedural style at once. At least mine is not ;)
Last part is to just write down EVERY SINGLE STEP. Than assemble them together. And you're done. Congratulations.

Comment: Actually a lot of people are programming all the time. From cleaning a room to cooking a meal, to organising a party. Oh and always check your intuition, sometimes, it's not the guy with one eyebrow who did it. :)

Comment: And some people apply algorithmic strategies when analyzing social relationships. Yup ^^

Answer (score 1):

When one starts to learn programming, language syntax is a logical starting point. It enables a budding programmer to properly express their ideas and formulations in code that will run. However, as you correctly pointed out, syntax means little in the "larger scheme" of programming.

I don't know what the tutorials you have read cover in terms of that "larger scheme", and I can't think of any specific tutorials or books of the top of my head. But, I would recommend finding a resource that will teach you about **data structures**. If you are unfamiliar with the concept, a data structure is a very fundamental topic in computer science. The topic comes about from the following question: *"How does one process, store, and access information efficiently with regards to time and memory usage?"*

For many CS students in college, a class heavy in data structures would be their 2nd course after an intro like the one you've described, and usually where the real computer science begins. Also, data structures will provide you with a foundation worthy of moving on to studying **algorithms**, a more major concept in computer science that deals with how one solves problems in a logical, step-by-step, and most importantly, reproducible and scalable way.

Once again, I apologize for not having any links, but I hope I've provided you with some topics to jump-start some google or amazon searches. Good luck with your autodidactic pursuit of CS!

Comment: I agree Isaac, Data Structures are a great fundamental skill to learn. OP: I challenge you to write a LinkedList implementation in whatever language you are comfortable using. Use whatever resources necessary in order to learn how to do it. It should be able to insert to the front, remove any element, and search for any element. Once this is done, use the knowledge you've learned to build a binary tree.

Comment: Mind me to disagree with that? In my opinion, data structures aren't that much of a deal - they are more patchworking tools, so you don't have to do the thinking other people have already done. Re-inventing the wheel. You know? But they don't do much to help understanding programming. You can know all famous design patterns in whatever language you are. You can know all about efficient storage. You can know all language quirks. And still write inefficient or buggy algorithms.

Comment: Johannes: In my opinion, data structures are fundamental and quite important for computer science. I am no professor, but I'm sure many would agree. Of course anyone, no matter how well learned, can write an inefficient or buggy algorithm. But, for example, give a programmer the knowledge and understanding as to why they should use a map instead of a vector for a specific problem, and you make them that much more capable.

Comment: Language syntax is a logical ending point as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @IsaacDrachman: I'm sorry I have to disagree again. At least somewhat. While what you said may be true for some people, I, myself, came up with the most of the fundamental data structures before I ever heard about them (of course most of them were not very efficient at first). And I, personally, find it quite intuitive what structure to use for what purpose. For me it's more the way 'round: I know exactly what structure I need, and have trouble finding one amongst whatever API that suits my needs, so for me it's more about learning implementation details than the structures themselves.

Comment: There's a rule in programming that if you get the data structure right, the code to use it becomes obvious. It's true but it's not entirely obvious how to get the data structure "right" : (

Answer (score 0):

You have to have an aim or a goal make a project for yourself, plan it and go do it. You'll learn loads on the way and if you ever get stuck, then just post a question. :) I know it is all to easy to just learn from books, videos and online tutorials but as soon as you start creating things yourself, you'll get better and better at creating things and thus you become a god :) I mean programmer.